# python regex word repeat time

Tags: python, regex

I got the following scenarios:

```
1) car collisions effect 3 right lanes
2) 3 car collisions effect right lanes
```

I want to figure out number of lanes instead of number of collision. To be specific I want extract number and "right lanes" with less than two \bwords\b in between.

```
\b(\d)<I want to limit 2 words here>\s*(lane[s]?)
OR
\b(\d)<I want to limit 10 characters here>\s*(lane[s]?)
```

Comment: what output should you get from your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lookahead:

```
import re
s1 = "1) car collisions effect 3 right lanes"
s2 = "2) 3 car collisions effect right lanes"
print re.findall("(\d+)(?=(?:\s+\w+){,2}\s+right lanes)", s1) 
print re.findall("(\d+)(?=(?:\s+\w+){,2}\s+right lanes)", s2)
```

*Gives:*

```
['3']
[]
```

Comment: this solved my question. Thx. I had the similar solution but I used {2} instead of {,2}. Python re documentation used {m} instead of {,m}, but it was wrong